# How to match unique ID from the different table in database and retrieve data according to that unique ID in Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, servlets, match, fuzzy

Table **user** in database(postgresql) has unique id for each user, dob, first and last names of the user;
Table **points** in database has userID and gamePoints columns.

In java servlet, how do I match and retrieve who exactly that user is with points and output? Fuzzy Match??

example:

```
Table user:
userID-name-lastname-dob
1-Edward-Maka-1950
2-Kapu-Aka-1990
3-Park-Lewins-1993

Table points:
userID-gamePoints
1-320
3-3312
2-1001
```

Comment: "*how do I match ... who exactly that user is*" based on which input? What does your servlet get as a parameter?

Comment: it may get first or last name. So, then it should look for unique ID in the same table. After that, look other specified table to match that uniqueID and retrieve the rest info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this just a matter or writing an appropriate query and parsing the results from the ResultSet in Java?

The query should be something like:

```
SELECT user.userID, user.name, user.lastname, user.dob, points.gamePoints
FROM user, points
WHERE user.userID = points.userID 
  AND (user.name = ? OR user.lastname = ?)
```

Comment: Yep!! it was and I did not know this before :) Thanks. How may I implement this to Java? Just as usual??

Comment: @krest There are good jdbc tutorial available online. Here is one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html